# Slow Requests on Local Flask Server

Tags: python, flask

Just starting to play around with Flask on a local server and I'm noticing the request/response times are way slower than I feel they should be.

Just a simple server like the following takes close to 5 seconds to respond.

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return "index"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Any ideas? Or is this just how the local server is?

Comment: Its not the local server but it might have to do with other applications running in the background what OS are you running this on?

Comment: I'm running on OS X 10.7 on a i7 iMac

Comment: It should not be taking this long for your responses but I have actually messed around with flask before to no success I would advise [Bottlepy](http://bottlepy.org/). Though still check your background processes you might have an older version of your server running in the background taking over your python and causing your slow responses. Also it could be your browser does this happen in chrome & safari?

Comment: @Meroon's answer was correct for me. Rather than changing the host settings, however: Might I recommend simply using 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost? That solved the problem without changing the system configuration.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Ok I figured it out. It appears to be an issue with Werkzeug and os's that support ipv6.

From the Werkzeug site http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/serving/:

> On operating systems that support ipv6 and have it configured such as modern Linux systems, OS X 10.4 or higher as well as Windows Vista some browsers can be painfully slow if accessing your local server. The reason for this is that sometimes “localhost” is configured to be available on both ipv4 and ipv6 socktes and some browsers will try to access ipv6 first and then ivp4.

So the fix is to disable ipv6 from the localhost by commenting out the following line from my hosts file:

```
::1             localhost
```

Once I do this the latency problems go away.

I'm really digging Flask and I'm glad that it's not a problem with the framework. I knew it couldn't be.

Comment: I found these useful:
Windows
http://www.techunboxed.com/2012/08/how-to-disable-ipv6-in-windows-8.html

Ubuntu
http://www.noobslab.com/2012/05/disable-ipv6-if-your-internet-is.html

Comment: thanks a lot!  suddenly dev testing is snappy and responsive!  my only question:  as the Mac hosts file indicates that removing localhost could affect my Mac's operations, I wonder whether it is referring to this line (or the one that simply locates localhost to 127.0.0.1

Comment: on my windows 10 system in the hosts file both entries (ip4 and ip6) are commented out; they are resolved by the DNS system. I got a huge speed increase when i ran the server on "127.0.0.1" instead of "localhost" (from 2.0 to 0.003 secs for simple calls)

Comment: Thank you for this answer! Although my situation was a bit different (running nose2 against aiosmtpd), your answer gave me a hint: When I _disable IPv6_ on my Windows 10 laptop speeds up things like 10x or 100x !!

Comment: This answer did not work for me, but the answer with threads worked dramatically.

Answer (score 101):

Add "threaded=True" as an argument to app.run(), as suggested here:
http://arusahni.net/blog/2013/10/flask-multithreading.html

For example: `app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=8080, threaded=True)`

The ipv6-disabling solution did not work for me, but this did.

Comment: Passing `--threaded` to my `manage.py` using `Flask-Script` worked too.

Comment: For those who get it "fixed" by enabling threads, be warned! In this case the delay was caused by the previous request not being closed properly, so now it is actually [just stacking a lot of threads](http://i.stack.imgur.com/lRUpS.png).

Comment: Thank you sir for making my localhost run blazingly fast.

Comment: @snolflake: Is there a way to know whether the requests aren't being closed properly?

Comment: @Kylotan There's probably a way to do that. However it's been a while since I worked with python so I can't be of much help right now. Sorry.

Comment: From the command line I used `flask run --with-threads` which solved my problem.

Comment: Dramatic difference: from many seconds to a tiny fraction of a second. But now I have to chase my code to see if there is an improperly closed request somewhere.

Answer (score 27):

Instead of calling `http://localhost:port/endpoint` call `http://127.0.0.1:port/endpoint`. 
This removed the initial 500ms delay for me.

Comment: for me it removed something like 3seconds (I moved form 0.0.0.0 to 127.0.0.1).
Can somebody explain why and how it works?

Comment: Why in gods name does this work? Went from 2.06 seconds to 0.002 seconds. Browser is able to use localhost without problem, but requests.get on localhost takes 2 seconds to resolve.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71919526/flask-post-request-optimization/71919719#71919719

Answer (score 15):

The solution from @sajid-siddiqi is technically correct, but keep in mind that the built-in *WSGI* server in **Werkzeug** (which is packaged into **Flask** and what it uses for `app.run()`) is only single-threaded.

Install a *WSGI* server to be able to handle multi-threaded behavior. I did a bunch of research on various *WSGI* server performances. Your needs may vary, but if all you're using is **Flask**, then I would recommend one of the following webservers.

Update (2020-07-25): It looks like **gevent** started supporting *python3* 5 years ago, shortly after I commented that it didn't, so you can use **gevent** now.

**gevent**

You can install **gevent** through **pip** with the command `pip install gevent` or **pip3** with the command `pip3 install gevent`. Instructions on how to modify your code accordingly are here: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/deploying/wsgi-standalone/#gevent

**meinheld**

**gevent** is better, but from all the benchmarks I've looked at that involve real-world testing, **meinheld** seems to be the most straightforward, simplistic *WSGI* server. (You could also take a look at **uWSGI** if you don't mind some more configuration.)

You can also install **meinheld** through **pip3** with the command `pip3 install meinheld`. From there, look at the sample provided in the **meinheld** source to integrate **Flask**: https://github.com/mopemope/meinheld/blob/master/example/flask_sample.py

*NOTE: From my use of *PyCharm*, the line `from meinheld import server` highlights as an error, but the server will run, so you can ignore the error.

Comment: I had major performance problems with Flask, even simplest requests were taking about 0.5s to finish. Just switched to gevent and everything works flawlessly, thank you!

Answer (score 10):

My problem was solved by "threaded=True", but I want to give some background to distinguish my problem from others for which this may not do it.

1. My issue only arose when running Flask with python3. Switching to python2, I no longer had this issue.
2. My problem manifested *only* when accessing the api with Chrome, at which point, Chrome displayed the expected screen, but everything else hung (curl, ffx, etc) until I either reloaded or closed the Chrome tab, at which point everything else that was waiting around returned a result.

My best guess is that Chrome was trying to keep the session open and Flask was blocking the subsequent requests. As soon as the connection from Chrome was stopped or reset, everything else was processed.

In my case, threading fixed it. Of course, I'm now going through some of the links others have provided to make sure that it's not going to cause any other issues.

Answer (score 6):

`threaded=True` works for me, but finally I figured out that the issue is due to foxyproxy on firefox. Since when the flask app is running on localhost, slow response happens if

- foxyproxy is enabled on firefox

slow response won't happen if

- foxyproxy is disabled on firefox
- access the website using other browsers

The only solution I found is to disable foxyproxy, tried to add localhost to proxy blacklist and tweak settings but none of them worked.

Answer (score 6):

I used Miheko's response to solve my issue.

`::1     localhost` was already commented out on my hosts file, and setting `Threaded=true` didn't work for me. Every REST request was taking 1 second to process instead of being instant.

I'm using python 3.6, and I got flask to be fast and responsive to REST requests by making flask use gevent as its WSGI.

To use gevent, install it with `pip install gevent`

Afterwards, I used the https://gist.github.com/viksit/b6733fe1afdf5bb84a40#file-async_flask-py-L41 to set flask to use gevent.

Incase the link goes down, here's the important parts of the script:

```
from flask import Flask, Response
from gevent.pywsgi import WSGIServer
from gevent import monkey

# need to patch sockets to make requests async
# you may also need to call this before importing other packages that setup ssl
monkey.patch_all()

app = Flask(__name__) 


# define some REST endpoints... 

def main():

    # use gevent WSGI server instead of the Flask
    # instead of 5000, you can define whatever port you want.
    http = WSGIServer(('', 5000), app.wsgi_app) 

    # Serve your application
    http.serve_forever()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: threaded=True is not working for (using python 3.6.7 and postman), I am getting VersionConflict: (greenlet 0.4.13 (c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages), Requirement.parse('greenlet>=0.4.14; platform_python_implementation == "CPython"')), may I know how to resolve this, Thanks

Comment: cut times in half. thank u good sir.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error when running on hosts other than `localhost` as well, so for some, different underlying problems may exhibit the same symptoms.

I switched most of the things I've been using to Tornado, and anecdotally it's helped an amount. I've had a few slow page loads, but things seem generally more responsive. Also, very anecdotal, but I seem to notice that Flask alone will slow down over time, but Flask + Tornado less so. I imagine using Apache and `mod_wsgi` would make things even better, but Tornado's really simple to set up (see http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/deploying/others/).

(Also, a related question: [Flask app occasionally hanging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13333684/flask-app-occasionally-hanging))

Answer (score 1):

I had a different solution here. I just deleted all `.pyc` from the server's directory and started it again.
By the way, localhost was already commented out in my hosts file (Windows 8).

The server was freezing the whole time and now it works fine again.

Answer (score 1):

I run Python 3.8.10 which works fine, but as soon as I switch to Python 3.10.6 responses will be awful slow.

I could get around this problem with changing the precedence to IPv4 in /etc/gai.conf