# Flask requests are stalled for 300ms

Tags: python, google-chrome, flask

I have the following flask server:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/test")
def test():
    return 'OK'

app.run()
```

If I run this with `python main.py` and go to `localhost:5000/test` in Chrome, sometimes the request completes in 5ms but sometimes it is "stalled" for 300ms.

[image: Flask network traffic]

This seems more likely to happen if I wait between requests (a few minutes) or if I do a hard refresh in Chrome.

I am using:

- Flask: 1.0.2
- Chrome: v72 (with extensions disabled)
- OS: Windows 10

Anyone know what could be causing this or how to fix it (while still using Flask's dev server)?

**EDIT**
I tried using 127.0.0.1 (as suggested by Sraw) and the 300ms delay went away. I'm still curious why this isn't working with `localhost` though.

Comment: this will help you [Slow Requests on Local Flask Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11150343/slow-requests-on-local-flask-server)

Comment: I tried the first 2 solutions from @prashantrana's link but I'm still seeing the same issue

Comment: Have you tried using `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`?

Comment: @Sraw ah the problem goes away when I use 127.0.0.1!

Comment: Cool! That's an interesting problem about DNS resolving. Your OS is trying to use ipv6 address for `localhost` first but fail. Then fallback to ipv4 address.

Comment: @rob ,it's great your problem is solved now . you can also use  accepted solution by OP from  #Meroon is solving the issue where he disable ipv6 from the localhost by commenting out the following line from hosts file.  with this insteal of using 127.0.0.1 , you can use localhost

Comment: I wouldn't say my issue is solved. Using 127.0.0.1 is a good workaround but I'm building a dev tool that others will run on localhost and see this issue. This line in the host file "::1             localhost" is commented out by default in windows 10 so that fix did not work.